# Set TERMOUT OFF is not working when I am using sqlplus in command prompt?

Tags: oracle, windows, sqlplus

I am using the sql statement listed below in my spool sql script, and I am executing this script from sqlplus. But in terminal query output is still coming and I am using sqlplus in command prompt. But when I tried, directly launching sqlplus.exe and using this script I am not getting query output in terminal.

Can someone please help on how to stop terminal output when I launch sqlplus from command prompt?

```
SET ECHO OFF
SET TERMOUT OFF
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET PAGESIZE 0  
SET LINESIZE 83
SET TRIMSPOOL ON
SET WRAP ON
SET RECSEP OFF

SPOOL '&1'

SELECT 
    DATA_OUT_DATA 
FROM 
    STAGE.DATA_TABLE
ORDER BY 
    DATA_UNIQ_ID,DATA_INV_ID, DATA_SEQ_NO;

SPOOL OFF

SET PAGESIZE 24
SET LINESIZE 80
SET FEEDBACK ON
SET TERMOUT ON
```

Answer (score 7):

[12.41.61 SET TERM[OUT] {ON | OFF}](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqpug/SET-system-variable-summary.html#GUID-6EB80C8B-7B25-419C-AB5D-769544096001)

> Controls the display of output generated by commands **in a script that
>   is executed with @, @@ or START.** OFF suppresses the display so that
>   you can spool output to a file without displaying the output on
>   screen. ON displays the output on screen. **TERMOUT OFF does not affect
>   output from commands you enter interactively or redirect to SQL*Plus
>   from the operating system.**

Put the above commands in a script, then call that script.

script.sql:

```
SET ECHO OFF
SET TERMOUT OFF
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET PAGESIZE 0  
SET LINESIZE 83
SET TRIMSPOOL ON
SET WRAP ON
SET RECSEP OFF

SPOOL '&1'

SELECT 
    DATA_OUT_DATA 
FROM 
    STAGE.DATA_TABLE
ORDER BY 
    DATA_UNIQ_ID,DATA_INV_ID, DATA_SEQ_NO;

SPOOL OFF

SET PAGESIZE 24
SET LINESIZE 80
SET FEEDBACK ON
SET TERMOUT ON
```

Then:

```
SQL> @script.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

There are three methods to put spool and query script into sql engine:

1, SqlplusWindow

```
SQL> SPOOL * select query * SPOOL OFF
```

2, SqlplusWindow

```
SQL> @spoolquery.sql
```

3, Shell Terminal or JOB

```
sqlplus -s "/as sysdba" << EOF_INCLUDE_SCRIPT>/dev/null 2>&1

YourSpool&QueryScriptHere

EOF_INCLUDE_SCRIPT
```

Here in Method3 the `-s` hides query script and `>/dev/null 2>&1` hides the query result output.